# New Column from Dictionary based on Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to create a new column that uses a dictionary to assign values based on some conditions from different columns.

Below is the Dictionary and Dataframe

```
fee = {
('CL',  'SB') :295,
('CL',  'NB') :150,
('BR',  'SB') :120,
('BR',  'NB') :120,
('AR',  'SB') :150,
('AR',  'NB') :150,
('CN',  'SB') :285,
('CN',  'NB') :215,
('MX',  'SB') :115,
('MX',  'NB') :115,
('UK',  'SB') :170,
('UK',  'NB') :120,
}


dateval= pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['CL', 'CL', 'MX', 'UK', 'CN', 'AR', 'AR', 'BR'],
                    'direction': ['SB', 'NB', 'SB', 'SB', 'NB', 'SB', 'SB', 'NB'],
                    'times': [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                    'amountdesired': [295,150,115,290,215,300,150,240]
                }   
                    
                    )
```

The code below works well when times = 1

```
dateval['amountdesired']=dateval.loc[(dateval['times'].isin([1]))][['Country', 'direction']].apply(tuple, axis=1 ).map(fee)
```

When times is = 2 I would like to use both values for Country

I understand I ultimately could change the structure of my dictionary but I was wondering if I could keep it a such and use some smart way to achieve this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what do you want the output to look like ?

Comment: The output is equal to the column "amountdesired"  Sorry should have specified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D.L's answer got me very close to my desired outcome.

this is how I solved

```
dateval['combined'] = dateval.apply(
    lambda row: fee[tuple([row['Country'],row['direction']])] if row['times'] == 1  else fee[tuple([row['Country'],'SB'])]+fee[tuple([row['Country'],'NB'])]  , axis=1)
```

Thanks all!

Comment: similarity noted:  glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your attempt was close by using the `apply()` method.

This is my recipe:

- make new column (called it combined).
- use `lambda` with `if row['times'] == 1` statement
- finally `else row['Country'] + " + " + row['direction']`

So with the above, you could do this:

```py
import pandas as pd

fee = {
('CL',  'SB') :295,
('CL',  'NB') :150,
('BR',  'SB') :120,
('BR',  'NB') :120,
('AR',  'SB') :150,
('AR',  'NB') :150,
('CN',  'SB') :285,
('CN',  'NB') :215,
('MX',  'SB') :115,
('MX',  'NB') :115,
('UK',  'SB') :170,
('UK',  'NB') :120,
}



dateval= pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['CL', 'CL', 'MX', 'UK', 'CN', 'AR', 'AR', 'BR'],
                    'direction': ['SB', 'NB', 'SB', 'SB', 'NB', 'SB', 'SB', 'NB'],
                    'times': [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                    'amountdesired': [295,150,115,290,215,300,150,240]
                }   
                    
                    )

# combine columns based on column3 values
dateval['combined'] = dateval.apply(
    lambda row: row['Country'] if row['times'] == 1 
    else row['Country'] + " + " + row['direction'], axis=1)

print(dateval)
```

Which gives this:

[image]

Comment: OP is trying to generate the `amountdesired` column, not a combination of `Country` and `direction`

Comment: @Nick,  you could well be right. i asked for an example of expected output, but none was given.  if so, it would be correct to change this answer.

Comment: Yeah, it seems OP is one of those who posts a question and goes away. I'm just basing my comment on the actual code in the question `dateval['amountdesired']=dateval.loc ...`

Comment: @Nick,  i see what you are saying. But i was thinking that if this was the case then what would be the criteria for selecting the numbers that go into that column ?!?  that's why i though it might be the answer i proposed...   i guess we will get clarity from the OP at some point.

Comment: I think where `times` is 1 you use the `fee` value that corresponds to the `(Country, direction)` tuple, when it's 2 you sum *all* `fee` values that corrrespond to the `Country` value, ignoring the `direction` value.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the help, I added the Column amountdesired as the example of what I would like the new column to be.

Comment: Nick, you are correct. That's the intent